# Golang, JSON - не могу разобрать поле, являющееся массивом структур

Tags: golang

Собственно, на входе - JSON следующего вида:

```
{
  "classifiers" : [ {
    "classifier_id" : "9a9388x45-nlc-1361",
    "url" : "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers/9a9388x45-nlc-1361",
    "name" : "data",
    "language" : "en",
    "created" : "2016-03-27T03:46:13.965Z"
  }, {
    "classifier_id" : "9a9388x45-nlc-1363",
    "url" : "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers/9a9388x45-nlc-1363",
    "name" : "data",
    "language" : "en",
    "created" : "2016-03-27T03:51:12.911Z"
  }, ... ]
}
```

Пытаюсь представить следующими структурами :

```
type WatsonClassifier struct {
    ClassifierID string `json:"classifier_id"`
    Language     string `json:"language"`
    url          string
    username     string
    password     string
}

type WatsonClassifierList struct {
    Classifiers []Classifier `json:"classifiers"`
}
```

Но в результате :

```
classifierList := WatsonClassifierList{}
json.Unmarshal(answer, &classifierList)
fmt.Println(classifierList)
```

Имею такой выхлоп :

```
{[<nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil>]}
```

Т.е. вместо классификаторов - nil. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Так ведь Unmarshall мне должен заполнить массив данными из JSON-а, не? А в JSON-е данные есть (собственно, показанный выше кусок - выхлоп `fmt.Println(string(answer))`). И да - если бы проблема была в этом, то откуда оно брало бы корректное число nil-в (элементов-то 8, как и должно быть).

Answer (score 1):

Однако, я сделал 2 очень глупые вещи :-)

1. Не обработал ошибку, возвращаемую `json.Unmarshal`.
2. Десериализовывал массив интерфейсов, а не конкретных типов (`[]Classifier` вместо `[]WatsonClassifier`).